# Windows Security Center Service can't be started

Tags: ms-security-essentials, security-center

Win 7 Home Prem 32-bit

I recently had a trojan detection by MS Security Essentials which it caught and quarantined.

I now get the following in the action center - The Windows Security Center Service can't be started.

MS Security Essentials doesn't seem to be present either despite me uninstalling and reinstalling.

I can set the security center service to start automatically but upon reboot it says the same thing? i.e. disabled   i can't get it to start and i can't seem to run MSSE - it just seems to open and close immediately?

Nothing obvious appears in the event viewer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add the name of the Trojan, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your system is still infected and Security Essentials wasn't able to stop all of the trojan's elements.

You might want to try and run an online virus scanner or attempt to install AVG Antivirus to see if the initial scan before install is able to catch the trojan.

Also, if you still remember the trojans name, try and find a clean-up tool from one of the various antivirus providers online.

Comment: Thanks for the replies all sound good.  Managed to find a recent restore point and restore that and all was back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Make a boot AV disc then boot from the disc and scan the hard drive, remove any infections it finds, I prefer the Kaspersky disc myself.

http://www.techmixer.com/free-bootable-antivirus-rescue-cds-download-list/

Then:
Install free MBAM, run the program and go to the Update tab and update it, then go to the Scanner Tab and do a quick scan, select and remove anything it finds.

http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html

When MBAM is done install SAS free version, run a quick scan, remove what it automatically selects.
http://www.superantispyware.com/download.html

These last 2 are not AV softwares like Norton, they are on demand scanners that only scan for nasties when you run the program and will not interfere with your installed AV software, these can be run once a week to ensure you are not infected. Be sure you update them before each weekly scan.

.

after you are sure the system is clean and MSE is still broken, try this MSE repair tool

http://www.itknowledge24.com/MSERT.zip

PDF on what the tool does
http://www.itknowledge24.com/MSE_Restore_Tool.pdf

.

Answer (score 0):

Your system is either still infected, or it has suffered serious damage because of the virus.

You might try to repair the Windows system files. See this article:
[How to Repair Windows 7 System Files with System File Checker](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html).

If this doesn't help, you might consider reformatting the hard disk and reinstalling Windows.
It is dangerous to use a computer that might still be infected.