# Windows Security Center turns off automatically

Tags: windows-7, security-center

The Security Center service stops automatically and switches from Start (automatic) to Disabled.

The computer (Windows 7 64 bit) is running Norman Anti Virus. What could be causing this?

**Update**

Norman found a possible virus. I uploaded the file to http://virusscan.jotti.org/en which reported the following virus names in the file:

- eorezo
- Win32:Diller-DK
- Trojan.PWS.Panda.2256
- Win32/Kryptik.AAKJ

So i think this problem is virus related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Click start > type Services.msc then hit enter.
2. Services Console will appear.
3. Find **Security Center** Service  on the right details pane >   right click it choose properties >
4. Security Center Properties should appear >   on the General Tab

   > set start-up type to automatic (Delayed start)
5. On service Status  Stop and then Start.

   If this does not works & error still continues then there are more chances 
   that your system is infected

   Also take a look at this question

   [Windows Security Center Service can't be started](https://superuser.com/questions/217114/windows-security-center-service-cant-be-started)

Comment: Thanks. The service automatically stops after one minute, and some virusscanners report a virus on the computer

Comment: @jao - Anti-virus being disabled on its own is nearly always a sign of malware.

Comment: You are welcome Jao :)
If viruses are tough to remove you should do Safe Mode scan (safe mode with networking.use F8 right before Windows starts to load ) to completely get rid off viruses.The benefit is that some processes and services are not loaded in Safe Mode so there is less chance that malware can load and interfere with the process. See more info here http://goo.gl/2QDGq