# Windows Security-Center service always disabled and Microsoft Security Essentials won't start

Tags: ms-security-essentials, virus, security-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get rid of malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

I'm not sure if I'm having some kind of infection on my mother's client.

When I logged in I noticed the Windows-Notification in the taskbar, saying that the security center has been disabled. While looking down there I also noticed that the icon of Microsoft Security Essentials had gone.

When I tried to start the security-center service from the taskbar, it would fail with an error. Checked services.msc and saw that it had been set to Disabled. Switched to Automatic, started the service and a few seconds after, it was disabled and stopped again.

Also tried starting MSE, but it wouldn't come up at all, not even the taskbar-icon. Now I've downloaded AVG, which found Adware.Ezula (but this doesn't look like it would disable MSE and the Security-Center service, from what I read in the description). I have checked the browser history for suspicious downloads, but I couldn't find anything.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: We have no way of knowing what infection is on your mother's computer. You have not used enough tools to determine if you are and/or are not infected with anything else nor have you determined if anything else except MSE is disabled. There are lot of things that can disable MSE including a corrupt windows installation.  We need to know exactly what errors appears when you tried to start MSE.  Use all the suggested programs contained in this answer http://superuser.com/questions/217114/windows-security-center-service-cant-be-started?rq=1

Comment: I would start by running a disk check, and then 'sfc.exe \SCANNOW' and see if there are disk or OS file issues.  Either way, what you are describing would drive me to rebuild the system regardless.